# Error al instalar Vue-CLI

Tags: vue.js

Al intentar instalar Vue según la guía oficial , me ocurre esto. ¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

> checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
>   npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules npm ERR! code EACCES npm
>   ERR! errno -13 npm ERR! syscall access npm ERR! Error: EACCES:
>   permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' npm ERR!  {
>   [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access
>   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'] npm ERR!   stack: npm ERR!    'Error:
>   EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/local/lib/node_modules\'',
>   npm ERR!   errno: -13, npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES', npm ERR!   syscall:
>   'access', npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' } npm ERR! 
>   npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system. npm ERR!
>   It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as
>   the current user npm ERR!  npm ERR! If you believe this might be a
>   permissions issue, please double-check the npm ERR! permissions of the
>   file and its containing directories, or try running npm ERR! the
>   command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).

Comment: En la primera línea da indicios de problemas con los permisos de escritura, ya intentaste ejecutar la consola como **administrador** ?

Comment: No se como hacerlo.Acabo de empezar

Comment: ¿Qué sistema operativo usas?

Comment: ....MacOs Mojave

Comment: Has probado con `sudo npm install -g @vue/cli`? Aunque no es recomendado instalar NPM como root creo que por razones de seguridad, si es sólo para aprender no le veo mayor inconveniente

Comment: Me da un poco de respeto sudo, pero voy a intentarlo

Comment: tengo el mismo problema, se pudo solucionar?

Answer (score 0):

Si con eso funciona o también se puede con npx, con npx no lo instalas localmente por lo cual suele tardar un poco más.

-npx @vue/cli create --default my-project

```
$ npx @vue/cli --help Usage: vue <command> [options]

Options:   -V, --version                              output the version number   -h, --help                                 output usage information

Commands:   create [options] <app-name>                create a new project powered by vue-cli-service   add [options] <plugin> [pluginOptions]     install a plugin and invoke its generator in an already created project   invoke [options] <plugin> [pluginOptions]  invoke the generator of a plugin in an already created project   inspect [options] [paths...]               inspect the webpack config in a project with vue-cli-service   serve [options] [entry]            serve a .js or .vue file in development mode with zero config   build [options] [entry]                    build a .js or .vue file in production mode with zero config   ui [options]                        start and open the vue-cli ui   init [options] <template> <app-name>   generate a project from a remote template (legacy API, requires @vue/cli-init)   config [options] [value]                   inspect and modify the config   outdated [options]                         (experimental) check for outdated vue cli service / plugins   upgrade [options] [plugin-name]            (experimental) upgrade vue cli service / plugins   info                                       print debugging information about your environment
Run vue <command> --help for detailed usage of given command.
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenia el mismo problema lo hice tecleando este comando

```
 sudo npm install -g @vue/cli.
```

en la terminal